# Can I access shadowed arguments when function returns a function

Tags: javascript

Consider the following snippet:

```
const returnsFunc = () => (arg0, arg1) => {
  console.log('arguments: ' + JSON.stringify(arguments));
  console.log('arg0: ' + arg0 + '  ' + JSON.stringify(arguments[0]));
  console.log('arg1: ' + arg1 + '  ' + JSON.stringify(arguments[1]));
};
returnsFunc()(1, 2);
```

The output is as follows:

```
arguments: {"0":{"isTrusted":true}}
(index):48 arg0: 1  {"isTrusted":true}
(index):49 arg1: 2  undefined
```

So the `arguments` variable for the function being returned from `returnsFunc` is being shadowed.

Is there a way to access the shadowed `arguments` variable?

Comment: Arrow functions don't have `arguments`.

Comment: An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function expression and does not have its own this, arguments, super, or new.target.

Comment: also the way you use arrow function reduce the readability i think,